# Example of URLProtocol usage?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, urlsession

I'm trying to figure out how URLProtocol works. Can you provide some cases of URLProtocol usage? What type of problems can it solve?

Comment: This article and demo might help you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2292-using-nsurlprotocol-with-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLProtocol allows you to insert yourself into the URL loading system. I've used that for several things, from [a simple offline caching system for UIWebView](http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol) to [intercepting Pandora traffic](https://github.com/jnjosh/PandoraBoy/blob/db2ddc20900f3fdb4590278893ea333bd511c6e7/ProxyURLProtocol.h).

I also sometimes implement my own schemes with an URLProtocol. For example, the server may send down a custom `resource:` link, and I'll use an URLProtocol to read that out of the bundle resources (basically the same as WKWebView's WKURLSchemeHandler for this).